# Empty cells appear in table view when implementing a custom UITableViewCell in XIB file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view controller `MasterCompiledReportViewController` and it has a view, inside that view there's a `tableview`. I have another xib file `MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell.xib` which has its own class as well, which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

I assigned the file owner of the xib file to `MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell`, I also selected the cell view inside the xib file and set the class to `MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell`. I set the `reuseIdentifier` as`MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell` as well.

This is the code for initialising the table:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell";
MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.lblDeviceName.text = @"Device Name";
    cell.lblTotalAmount.text = @"Total Sales Amount";
    return cell;
}
```

**The problem: The table loads with absolutely no data.**
Additional info: The custom cell has 2 labels.

**Edit**: I am setting the outlet of the tableview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.compiledReportTbl.delegate = self;
    self.compiledReportTbl.dataSource = self;
}
```

Comment: The code you provided is not complete. Check if you refer outlets for UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate fully. Also if you set your cell identifier in storyboard correctly. There is no need to init MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell again.

Comment: Yeah I set the outlet for the tableview in this class. I'm setting the delegate and datasource to self since I implemented the delegates.

Comment: Did you registerNib for your tableView? [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell" bundle:nil]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell"];

Comment: I think you got a small mistake when create xib, marking outlet, etc. Please re-checked and i believe you can find it out. Your code totally no problem

Comment: @Allen: Yes I just tried to register the nib in viewDidLoad as well. No luck! Can you please recommend a good tutorial to add custom tableview cells for ios 8 please?

Comment: Assigned the file owner of the xib file to MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell?  My suggestion is  removing it , assign the file class of the xib as MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell. try this!

Comment: @Shahnawaz I created a small project for you. You can compare the difference. I think the mistake would be very minor in your code. https://db.tt/85yO3C4W

Comment: Thanks so much Allen, it worked like a charm later! I deleted my custom classes and just did it from scratch your way :)

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this , may be this will help you :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell";
    MasterCompiledReportTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }
    cell.lblDeviceName.text = @"Device Name";
    cell.lblTotalAmount.text = @"Total Sales Amount";
    return cell
}
```